# Moving Limit within Probability/Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

**Edits in Bold**

When I look up the strong law of large numbers it says that **(Looking at Discrete Random Variables)**
$$P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\bar{X}_{n}=\mu\right)$$
That got me wondering are the following equivalent 
$$P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\bar{X}_{n}=\mu\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left(\bar{X}_{n}=\mu\right)$$

I tried to think of this question in terms or translate this question in terms of a Measure on some object (to think of it somewhat pictorially) but I didn't know how to translate the summing of more random variables to this that type of thinking.

**If this is not necessarily true are there conditions that would allow it to be true?**

Comment: If $\overline{X}_n$ is continuous, then $P(\overline{X}_n=\mu)=0$.

Comment: you are write I had discrete random variables in mind when writing this question but it seems that this still may not equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted already, if $\overline{X}_n$ is continuous, then $P(\overline{X}_n = \mu)=0$.

If the $X_n$ are discrete, then the averages $\overline{X}_n$ will also be discrete, but the space of values that they can take become arbitrarily large as $n \to \infty$. So, $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(\overline{X}_n=\mu)=0$, even though $P(\overline{X}_n = \mu)$ may be nonzero.

Comment: yea I guess Im having a hard time wrapping my head around between the difference of the the two different mean

Answer (score 2):

They are not.

If $\bar{X}_n$ is continuous, then $P(\bar{X}_n=c)=0$ for any constant $c$ (including the specific case $c=\mu$). So the limit on the RHS is just $0$ and the probability on the LHS is 1 (in the case when the SLLN applies.).

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right, is it possible this could be true for discrete random variables?

Comment: To OP: maybe you can get some intuition for the discrete case by working through a simple case in which each $X_i$ is Bernoulli.